# i have put a condition if phone number is empty, log it else sent it but condition is not excuting even if there is no phone number

Tags: java, android, excel, data-structures, sms

This is my send Sms activity please tell where is the problm even if there is no number the else condition is still excuting

```
public void sendMySMS() {
        Log.d(TAG, "sendMySMS: Activated");

        Intent i = getIntent();
        listOfAllMessages = i.getStringArrayListExtra("messages");
        listOfAllContacts = i.getStringArrayListExtra("contacts");
        size = listOfAllContacts.size();

        for (int j = 0; j < listOfAllContacts.size(); j++) {
            String phone = listOfAllContacts.get(j);
            String message = listOfAllMessages.get(j);

            if(phone.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "sendMySMS: " + phone);
                Log.d(TAG, "sendMySMS: " + message);
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "sendMySMS: " + phone);
                Log.d(TAG, "sendMySMS: " + message);
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sendStatusTextView.setText("Sending Messages");

                PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SendingSms.this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
                sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, message, sentIntent, null);
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: This code needs debugging nothing else .

Comment: try org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isBlank(String str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your log, make sure that the value of phone variable isn't a space instead of blank or `null`. `isEmpty()` returns true just in case of `""` and *`null`*.

Comment: "and null" no, not in this case.

Comment: just run the code in debug mode ..you can check your values there ..whats the actual value of phone variable. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html try this.

Comment: @AndyTurner actually i'm reading a excel file where first column is messages and second is contact so i created a file where column of contacts is empty and i'm reading that file and i want to stop sending messages when there is no contact but instead of if condition the else condition excutes..

Comment: @SantanuSur what if there is a space then what should i do?

Answer (score -1):

You need to try doing this!

```
public void sendMySMS() {
    Log.d(TAG, "sendMySMS: Activated");

    Intent i = getIntent();
    listOfAllMessages = i.getStringArrayListExtra("messages");
    listOfAllContacts = i.getStringArrayListExtra("contacts");
    size = listOfAllContacts.size();

    for (int j = 0; j < size.size(); j++) {
        String phone = listOfAllContacts.get(j);
        String message = listOfAllMessages.get(j);

        if(phone.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "sendMySMS: " + phone);
            Log.d(TAG, "sendMySMS: " + message);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "sendMySMS: " + phone);
            Log.d(TAG, "sendMySMS: " + message);
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sendStatusTextView.setText("Sending Messages");

            PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SendingSms.this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
            sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, message, sentIntent, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: wait **`WHY`** this `size.size()`

Comment: you putting all your data to   into size = listOfAllContacts.size()  so check size

Comment: the `size()` method returns the int size of a arraylist and my question is `WHY` **`size.size()`**

Comment: @Nilu i know that ``listOfAllContacts`` that is array but what is size that you using to store your ``listOfAllContacts``  detail

Comment: actually that size is used for another method just forget about it tell me why my if condition is not excuting even there are no contacts?